# Openrowset between DB2 (32bit) and SQL Server (64bit)

Tags: sql-server-2008, db2, 32bit-64bit, openrowset

```
select * from
OPENROWSET('IBMDADB2'
,'DSN=MY_DSN;UID=MY_UID;pwd=MY_PWD;'
,'select * from MY_TABLE')
```

When I run this in the SQL Server Management Studio, I get an error:

> No se puede crear una instancia del proveedor OLE DB "IBMDADB2" para el servidor vinculado "(null)".

This works ok when both db engines are 32bit, but the thing is; I can't upgrade one or downgrade another, because these are production databases. Is there a fixpack or sp that I can run to make this work?

Running *select @@version*:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)
Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008
Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit)
on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

and DB2 9.7

Comment: Can you translate the error message into English? Not everyone here understands Spanish ...

Comment: See if this [IBM TechNote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21219288) helps. You need to properly register the DB2 provider.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds:
- you can install additional instance 32bit SQL (e.g. SQLExpress) for work with OPENROWSET
- insert OPENROWSET into stored procedure on simple database
- then on production x64 SQL you can create **linked server** to 32bit SQL instance.
- use linked server to access database and stored procedure with OPENROWSET